# JPA: Select query fetch both parent and child

Tags: java, jpa

I'm using JPA with Eclipse Link implementation.

I have the following relation between UserAccount and UserDetail:

*User account:*

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private UserDetail userDetail;
```

*User detail:*

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="userDetail")
private UserAccount userAccount;
```

*I'm trying to fetch one UserAccount from the DB:*

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<UserAccount> shell = builder.createQuery(UserAccount.class);

Root<UserAccount> entity = shell.from(UserAccount.class);
shell.select(entity);
shell.distinct(true);

List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if (id != null){
    ParameterExpression<Integer> param = builder.parameter(Integer.class, "id");
    predicateList.add(builder.equal(entity.get("id"), param));
}

if (predicateList.size() == 1){
    shell.where(predicateList.get(0));
} else {
    Predicate[] p = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
    p = predicateList.toArray(p);
    shell.where(builder.and(p));
}   

TypedQuery<UserAccount> selectQuery =  em.createQuery(shell);
if (id != null) selectQuery.setParameter("id", id);
return selectQuery.getResultList();
```

This query searches for the users by ID. The problem is that in the result UserAccount doesn't have a UserDetail entity even though I used `(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`. What am I missing?

Comment: Enable logging, what SQL is generated? Is it correct?  Is the data on the database?

Comment: Yes the data is in the database and the SQL is correct generated

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined on which column in the database JPA should base itself to perform the join-operation.